# Preventing Hostname Redirects

Tags: java, http, redirect

I'm accessing a specific hostname in my `Java` application which I don't want to be redirected to somewhere else. It is using `HTTP` and not `HTTPS`. Is a redirect from the outside even possible? I thought of checking if the `hosts` file on `Windows` contains an entry that may redirect the hostname:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.SystemUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class HostsFileChecker
{
    public static boolean isPossiblyRedirecting(String hostName) throws IOException
    {
        if (!SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS)
        {
            return false;
        }

        File hostsFile = new File("C:\\Windows\\System32\\drivers\\etc\\hosts");
        String hostsFileContents = FileUtils.readFileToString(hostsFile).toLowerCase();
        return hostsFileContents.contains(hostName.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Is there something else that should be checked or does this make no sense to even do? Java is definitely "fooled" by a redirect in this Windows `hosts` file and access my local web server instead:

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to verify the identity of the server. SSL certificate on the server with a trusted CA is one way to accomplish this.

Comment: @Vasco:
That might be too overkill for my humble purposes